# Azure web app container and docker commands

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm using the Azure resource "Web app for containers" with a Linux docker image. I would like to use docker commands such as "docker inspect" but I'm not sure how this is possible. Via the Kudo interface this doesn't seem possible. I cannot even get the SHA256 hash of the image currently deployed. All I have is the initial docker run command executed by the app service itself.

Does anyone know how such operations can be executed with app containers in Azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Web app for container is different from the container. It is a web app service when you create it. The difference is that it comes out from a container.

So you cannot execute a docker command to a web app. You can execute the command of the web app.

For example, if you want to check the container image, the command is `az webapp config container show --resource-group groupName --name webName` and the result like this:

[image]

For more details about Web app command, see [Web App commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Thanks for the command, there are some interesting options to explore event though I think most of this information is also available in the azure portal. I think it's a shame there is not the option to at least see the digest.

Comment: Yeah, the information looks a bit less about the container. Maybe it will get improved in the future.