# Azure app service doesn't install docker properly

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, docker-daemon

I am currently trying to start ElasticSearch on an Azure app service using Docker. I install docker through the ssh available in azure app services. Docker seem to install alright in the console, however when I run

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

I get the following error in the ssh console:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have installed and uninstall Docker several times, however I still get the same error

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258338/azure-web-app-container-and-docker-commands

Answer (score 2):

Azure App service does not allow you to run Elastic Search due to its limitations

You may use Elastic as a Service on Azure or install it in AKS or VM.

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/elastic.ec-azure?tab=Overview

You are trying to install Docker inside the Docker container

App Service for Linux comes with a bunch of preconfigured containers such as Node, PHP, Java, Python, Ruby and .NET Core.
[image]

https://anthonychu.ca/post/jekyll-azure-app-service-linux/

The exact issue you mentioned means that Docker daemon is not started in your Linux environment

To start the Docker daemon use command:

```
systemctl start docker
```